# Dynamically load images, break loop on image error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load images to a table dynamically without having to use server side code. It works, but I want to be able to have an infinite loop that breaks when a picture fails to load, rather than hard code the number of rows I need. That way I won't ever have to update the code, I'll just be able to add pictures to a folder if I want to expand the table.

Right now the "onerror" attribute hides the failed image, but I also want to break out of the outer loop (loop1).

```
function headCatalogLoader() {
var table = document.getElementById("catalog");
var meshNum = 0;
var uniqueID = 0;

loop1:
for (var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {  // i made it 50 instead of infinite for now
    var row = table.insertRow(i);

    loop2:
    for (var k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {      // 2 is because 3 columns
        var skinTone = "none";
        var cell = row.insertCell(k);

        if (k == 0) {
            skinTone = "lgt";
        }
        else if (k == 1) {
            skinTone = "med";
        }
        else if (k == 2) {
            skinTone = "drk";
        }

        cell.innerHTML = "<img src=\"headimgs/head" + skinTone + meshNum + ".png\" id=\"head" + uniqueID + skinTone + "\" onclick=\"previewIt(this)\" onerror=\"$(this).hide();\" />";

        uniqueID++;
    }
    meshNum++;
}
var tbody = $("table tbody");
tbody.html($("tr",tbody).get().reverse());
}
```

Breaking from within the attribute is out of the loop's scope and doesn't work. Also using

```
$('img').on("error", function () {
    break loop1;
});
```

inside loop2 doesn't do anything. Any help or suggestions would be wonderful!

Comment: try `return` on error

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara If you use `return` in the "error" callback it will just end the callback.

Comment: The image will be rendered asynchronously; the loop will have necessarily completed by then unless you do something like `await` a `Promise` on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recursion method that you can implement for the above requirement, I have used timeout because the image load may take time if, So error could occur after loading few hundreds of images, feel free to adjust the timeout interval.

Below implementation will load 10 images per second.

```
var imageLoadError = false;

function loadImage() {
    if (imageLoadError) {
        return;
    }

    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.onerror = function () {
        imageLoadError = true;
    }

    img.src = '/image/url/here'; // THE NEXT IMAGE TO LOAD

    setTimeout(function () {
        loadImage()
    }, 100); // <= Timeout Interval
}
```

---

If performance is not critical, Here is the most recommanded way of doing it.

```
var imageLoadError = false;

function loadImage() {
    if (imageLoadError) {
        return;
    }

    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.onerror = function () {
        imageLoadError = true;
    }

    img.onload = function () {
        loadImage();
    }

    img.src = '/image/url/here'; // THE NEXT IMAGE TO LOAD
}
```

In this second implementation, the next image only loads after the last image is loaded. So this strategy will be slower than the first one.

In both implementation just call `loadImage()` once and it will do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how this would work for me. How will this function know what the image source is if it's outside of the loop? Would I have to completely rewrite my whole function in order to use this?

Comment: This is a recursion method you don't need any kind of loop, the method will execute itself after the completion

Comment: How would this break my outer loop? How would it know what the image source is?

Comment: "Would I have to completely rewrite my whole function in order to use this?" Yes you will have to do it

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what I am asking. I need the nested loops to create a table, the loops also load the images. The images have a specific naming scheme that corresponds to the iterations. I can't remove the loops. I also rejected your edit because the loop1: and loop2: are labels, not comments.